# Drawing gluino with feynmf

Tags: feynmf

Is it possible to draw gluino instead of curly or gluon line in feynmf (gluino line is zigzag with a line inside or curly with a line inside) Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{fmffile}{feynman/phase_space}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
\fmfleft{p1,p2}
\fmfright{t1,t2,chi1,chi2,t3,t4}
\fmf{fermion}{p1,vp}
\fmf{fermion}{p2,vp}
\fmflabel{$ P $}{p1}
\fmflabel{$ P $}{p2}
\fmflabel{$ t $}{t1}
\fmflabel{$ \bar{t} $}{t2}
\fmflabel{$ t $}{t3}
\fmflabel{$ \bar{t} $}{t4}
\fmflabel{$ \widetilde{\chi}_1^0 $}{chi1}
\fmflabel{$ \widetilde{\chi}_1^0 $}{chi2}
\fmf{curly,label=$\widetilde{g}$, label.side=right, tension=2}{vp,vg1}
\fmf{curly,label=$\widetilde{g}$, label.side=left, tension=2}{vp,vg2}
\fmf{plain}{vg1,t1}
\fmf{plain}{t2,vg1}
\fmf{dashes}{vg1,chi1}
\fmf{plain}{vg2,t3}
\fmf{plain}{t4,vg2}
\fmf{dashes}{vg2,chi2}
\fmfblob{.15w}{vp}
\fmfdot{vg1,vg2}
\fmffreeze
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p1,__vp) shifted (thick*(0,2))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p1,__vp) shifted (thick*(1,-1.5))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p2,__vp) shifted (thick*(0,2))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p2,__vp) shifted (thick*(1,-3))}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by adding following one can draw gluino line:

```
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__vp,__vg1) shifted (thick*(0,0))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__vp,__vg2) shifted (thick*(0,0))}
```

here is the full code (a bit changed):

```
![\begin{fmffile}{phase_space1}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,120)
\fmfleft{p1,p2}
\fmfright{t1,t2,chi1,chi2,t4,t3}
\fmf{fermion}{p1,vp}
\fmf{fermion}{p2,vp}
\fmflabel{$ P $}{p1}
\fmflabel{$ P $}{p2}
\fmflabel{$ t $}{t1}
\fmflabel{$ \bar{t} $}{t2}
\fmflabel{$ t $}{t3}
\fmflabel{$ \bar{t} $}{t4}
\fmflabel{$ \widetilde{\chi}_i^0 $}{chi1}
\fmflabel{$ \widetilde{\chi}_i^0 $}{chi2}
\fmf{curly,label=$\widetilde{g}$, label.side=right, tension=2}{vp,vg1}
\fmf{curly,label=$\widetilde{g}$, label.side=left, tension=2}{vp,vg2}
\fmf{plain}{vg1,t1}
\fmf{plain}{t2,v1}
\fmf{dashes}{v1,chi1}
\fmf{plain}{vg2,t3}
\fmf{plain}{t4,v2}
\fmf{dashes}{v2,chi2}
\fmf{dashes,label=$\widetilde{t}_1^*$, label.side=left}{vg1,v1}
\fmf{dashes,label=$\widetilde{t}_1^*$, label.side=right}{vg2,v2}
\fmfblob{.15w}{vp}
\fmfdot{vg1,vg2}
\fmffreeze
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p1,__vp) shifted (thick*(0,2))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p1,__vp) shifted (thick*(1,-1.5))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p2,__vp) shifted (thick*(0,2))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__p2,__vp) shifted (thick*(1,-3))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__vp,__vg1) shifted (thick*(0,0))}
\fmfi{plain}{vpath (__vp,__vg2) shifted (thick*(0,0))}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

[image: gluino decay]

Comment: How about making your answer contain a *complete* example together with the output as an image?